# Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_R \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n } 1_{[0,1]} (x) d\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

As the title says I have to first proof the existence and the calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_R \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n } 1_{[0,1]} (x) d\lambda$$

My idea:

Because of the indicator-function I can rewrite the integral and go from $R$ to the interval $[0,1]$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n }  d\lambda$$

because $(1+x)^n > 1+nx $ follows from the Bernoulli inequality

$\frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n}<1 =:M$ and the existence follows from the dominated convergence Theorem.

Can I the continue this way? :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n }  d\lambda= $$

$$\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n }  d\lambda= \int_0^1 0 d\lambda = 0$$

Comment: It is fine as long as you explain why $\lim \frac {1+nx}{(1+x)^{n}}=0$.

Comment: Using d'Hospital: $\lim \frac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n}=\lim \frac{x}{(1+x)^n*log(1+x)}= 0 $ for x in (0,1]

ok if x=0  i would have to use d#hospital once again.

Comment: Better way: expand $(1+x)^{n}$ up to the term in $x^{2}$.